# What offset is used for DocusignApi Envelope.completedDateTime

Tags: datetime, docusignapi, timezone-offset, envelope, offsetdatetime

I'm trying to do some DateTime calculations based off of the `Envelope` `completedDateTime` retrieved using the Docusign Java Api, but there is no offset included.
How do I determine what offset is being used?

the github location is: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/docusign/esign/model/Envelope.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean which timzeone it is at, and it *should be* UTC+0, or Greenwich Mean Time, or Zulu (has many names) but basically it's the one without any offset...

Comment: Thank you for confirming that. I was able to hit the endpoint and get some test data. It had the zone of “Z” which is UTC, like you said